# XSL-FO. Advanced Layout

Tags: xsl-fo

I've been using XSL-FO (Antennahouse is the target FO Engine) only for a short time. What I should implement is kind of a typographical layout where the texts should be placed in some well'defined boxes.

I have managed to get a first result by using

```
<fo:flow-map>
```

but I have the impression that's not the correct way to achieve my goal. In particular I have difficulties:

- to implement flows that comprise more pages   and
- the directive
  {fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="Erste"  maximum-repeats="1"} 
  seems not to work.

Is there anybody who could give me a tip? This is the xsl I have produced so far:

[my xsl-fo](http://www.fsalvi.net/test01.xml)

Comment: You should put a copy of your XML file on a website such as pastebin.com, as you're likely to delete it from your website one day, but this question on Stack Overflow will stay with a dead link...

Comment: And now it has a dead link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try xml2pdf by altsoft instead

Comment: Thank you. Does xml2pdf manage complex layouts? Could you give me some examples?

Comment: As far as I know they do support complex layout. You can contact their support and ask the samples.

Answer (score 2):

A flow-map is used to create areas linked together where content can flow from one box to another if the content fed into the flow area overflows the area specified for on part of the map. Think of a newspaper with a defined content and then a story, flowing from page 1 and continued on page 3. If that is what you are trying to accomplish, then flow-map is the right solution.

If as you state, you wish to place some text in a "well-defined box", then you do not need a flow-map. You simply use fo:block-container with a defined top, left, width and height whose position is absolute.